# Setting a timer on user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make tic-tac-toe with a timer. The timer which I've added starts when the page loads. How can I make this timer start only when first move is made? Also, Is it possible to change the default 'x' and set it to "o" or "x" as per user choice?  https://jsfiddle.net/ku1dmbzd/

```js
    var sec = 0;
    
    function pad(val) {
        return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
    }
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
    }, 1000);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    //tic-tac-toe
    
    (function Game() {
        // Elements
        var game = document.getElementById('game');
        var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('li');
        var resetGame = document.getElementById('reset-game');
        var turnDisplay = document.getElementById('whos-turn');
        var gameMessages = document.getElementById('game-messages');
        var playerOneScoreCard = document.getElementById('player-one-score');
        var playerTwoScoreCard = document.getElementById('player-two-score');
        
        // Vars
        var context = { 'player1' : 'x', 'player2' : 'o' };
        var board = [];
        
        var playerOneScore = 0;
        var playerTwoScore = 0;
        
        var turns;
        var currentContext;
        
        // Constructor
        var init = function() {
            turns = 0;
            
            // Get current context
            currentContext = computeContext();
            
            // Setup 3 x 3 board 
            board[0] = new Array(3);
            board[1] = new Array(3);
            board[2] = new Array(3);
            
            // bind events
            for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                boxes[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
            }
            
            resetGame.addEventListener('click', resetGameHandler, false);
        }
        
        //Keeps track of player's turn
        var computeContext = function() {
            return (turns % 2 == 0) ? context.player1 : context.player2;
        }
        
        // Bind the dom element to the click callback
        var clickHandler = function() {
            this.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
            
            this.className = currentContext;
            this.innerHTML = currentContext;
            
            var pos = this.getAttribute('data-pos').split(',');
            board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = computeContext() == 'x' ? 1 : 0;
            
            if(checkStatus()) {
                gameWon();
            }
            
            turns++;
            currentContext = computeContext();
            turnDisplay.className = currentContext;
        }
        
        
        // Check to see if player has won
        var checkStatus = function() {
            var used_boxes = 0;
            
            for(var rows = 0; rows < board.length; rows++ ) {
                var row_total = 0;
                var column_total = 0;
                
                for(var columns = 0; columns < board[rows].length; columns++) {
                    row_total += board[rows][columns];
                    column_total += board[columns][rows];
                    
                    if(typeof board[rows][columns] !== "undefined") {
                        used_boxes++;
                    }
                }
                
                // Winning combination for diagonal scenario [0,4,8], [2,4,6]
                var diagonal_tl_br = board[0][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][2]; // diagonal top left to bottom right
                var diagonal_tr_bl = board[0][2] + board[1][1] + board[2][0]; // diagonal top right bottom left
                
                if(diagonal_tl_br == 0 || diagonal_tr_bl == 0 || diagonal_tl_br == 3 || diagonal_tr_bl == 3) {
                    return true;
                }
                
                // Winning combination for row [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]
                // Winning combination for column [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8]
                // Only way to win is if the total is 0 or if the total is 3. X are worth 1 point and O are worth 0 points
                if(row_total == 0 || column_total == 0 || row_total == 3 || column_total == 3) {
                    return true;
                }
                
                // if all boxes are full - Draw!!!
                if(used_boxes == 9) {
                    gameDraw();
                }
            }
        }
        var gameWon = function() {
            clearEvents();
            
            // show game won message
            gameMessages.className = 'player-' + computeContext() + '-win';
            
            // update the player score
            switch(computeContext()) {
                case 'x':
                    playerOneScoreCard.innerHTML = ++playerOneScore;
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    playerTwoScoreCard.innerHTML = ++playerTwoScore;
            }
        }
        // Tells user when game is a draw.
        var gameDraw = function() {
            gameMessages.className = 'draw';
            clearEvents();
        }
        
        // Stops user from clicking empty cells after game is over
        var clearEvents = function() {
            for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                boxes[i].removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
            }
        }
        // Reset game to play again
        var resetGameHandler = function() {
            clearEvents();
            init();
    
            
            // Go over all the li nodes and remove className of either x,o
            // clear out innerHTML
            for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                boxes[i].className = '';
                boxes[i].innerHTML = '';
              
             //setTimeout(function () {
        //clearInterval(timer);
    
              
            }
            
            // Change Who's turn class back to player1
            turnDisplay.className = currentContext;
            gameMessages.className = '';
        }
        
        game && init();
    })();
```

```css
    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        background: #485b6e;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: Helvetica;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align:center;
    }
    
    h1 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        color: #f1f1f1
        
    }
    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 400px;
    }
    
    #game {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #dadada;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    #game > li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-decoration:none;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #f1f1f1;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 20px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #game > li.x {
        font-size: 40px;
        color: #ed4e6e
    }
    
    #game > li.o {
        font-size: 40px;
        color: #485b6e;
    }
    
    #game > li:hover {
        background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    
    #game > li:active {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 0;
    }
    
    #nfo {
        text-align:center;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    #whos-turn > span,
    #game-messages > span {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #whos-turn.x span.x,
    #whos-turn.o span.o, 
    #game-messages.player-x-win > span.player-x-win, 
    #game-messages.player-o-win > span.player-o-win,
    #game-messages.draw > span.draw {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    #reset-game {
        text-align: center;
            border: none;
            padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
            background: #ed4e6e;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 1em;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 3px 2px;
            border-radius: 2px;
    }
    
    #reset-game:hover {
            background: #2c3e52;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
            <ul id="game">
                <!-- first row -->
                <li data-pos="0,0"></li>
                <li data-pos="0,1"></li>
                <li data-pos="0,2"></li>
                <!-- second row -->
                <li data-pos="1,0"></li>
                <li data-pos="1,1"></li>
                <li data-pos="1,2"></li>
                <!-- third row -->
                <li data-pos="2,0"></li>
                <li data-pos="2,1"></li> 
                <li data-pos="2,2"></li>
            </ul>
            
            <button id="reset-game">Reset Game</button>
            
            <!-- Game Messages -->
            <div id="game-messages">
                <span class="player-x-win">Player One Wins</span>
                <span class="player-o-win">Player Two Wins</span>
                <span class="draw">Draw Game</span>
            </div>
            
            <aside id="nfo">
                <h2>Who's Turn</h2>
                <div id="whos-turn" class="x">
                    <span class="x">Player 1</span>
                    <span class="o">Player 2</span>
                </div>
               
              
              
              <h2>timer</h2>
                <span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>
                
                  
                  
                  <h2>Score Card</h2>
                <div id="score">
                    Player 1: <span id="player-one-score">0</span> <br />
                    Player 2: <span id="player-two-score">0</span> <br />
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will start the timer after the first click:

```
var timer;
document.getElementById( 'game' ).onclick = function(){

    timer = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
    }, 1000);
   this.onclick = null;

};
```

This is the html you provided for starting symbol choice:

```
<div id="pickerButton">
  <h2>Pick o or x</h2>
  <button class="pickerButton" type="button">X</button> 
  <button class="pickerButton" type="button">O</button> 
</div>
```

Add this somewhere inside the `Game` function:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName( 'pickerButton' );
buttons[0].onclick = function(){
    var context = { 'player1' : 'x', 'player2' : 'o' };
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
};
buttons[1].onclick = function(){
    var context = { 'player1' : 'o', 'player2' : 'x' };
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Edit: incorporated it all together - https://jsfiddle.net/ftfuh1oj/

Comment: I want users to make choice between symbols

Comment: @nafri After the user makes his choice you need to choose one of the two lines.

Comment: I want user to select either x or o before starting the game

Comment: @nafri If you could specify how the user makes the selection (providing the html at least), I will update the answer.

Comment: @nafri Edited, the code hides the `div` which means the selection will only  pop once before the first game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106404/discussion-between-nafri-and-janje).

Answer (score 2):

one way to select X or O before the game starts:

```
var xyChoice = prompt('player 1, do you want to be X\'s or O\'s');
var player2Marker;
if(xyChoice==='x'){player2Marker = 'o'}else{player2Marker = 'x'}
var context = { 'player1' : xyChoice, 'player2' : player2Marker };
```

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

Added Demo - [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ku1dmbzd/4/)

Set timer = null on page load:

`var timer = null;`

Then change your click handler to include this code:

```
var clickHandler = function() {
        this.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = setInterval(function () {
              document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
              document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
          }, 1000);
        }
        this.className = currentContext;
        this.innerHTML = currentContext;
        
        var pos = this.getAttribute('data-pos').split(',');
        board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = computeContext() == 'x' ? 1 : 0;
        
        if(checkStatus()) {
            gameWon();
        }
        
        turns++;
        currentContext = computeContext();
        turnDisplay.className = currentContext;
    }
```

Comment: You need to REPLACE the current clickHandler function that is inside the (function Game(){}) and only put the timer = null at the top. See https://jsfiddle.net/ku1dmbzd/4/

Comment: okay thanks. Should I add->   setTimeout(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
    To restart the timer when game restarts?

Comment: Yes, but it would be as simple as clearInterval(timer);

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ku1dmbzd/5/ Instead of restarting, this entirely stops the timer

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. Yes, so when the game stops, you will do the clearInterval(timer), and  move the line "var timer = null" into the init() function. Then when the game restarts, it will reset the timer to null and hit your null check on the first player move, thus starting the timer again.